# Jquery loading Problem

Tags: jquery

I have  a JSP Page like Below

```
< html >
< head >
< head >
< script type="text/javascript" src=../../jquery.js">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
alert("Page Is Loading....");   
    // Do Some
});

</script>

< body >
< span id="Refresh">
// here I wrote a Some HTML code
< %@include file="/../../some.jsp" %>
< /span>
< /body >
< / html >
```

The some.jsp also contains the some HTML element that are handled By
the some JQuery Function. But I did'nt include the jquery.js in some.jsp

All functions are working fine when first time is page loading.But
My Problem is,
   I try to refresh the span with an id value is Refresh, I am not able
to get the Jquery Functionality in between the Span Tag.But, The some.jsp
Jquery Function is work well after the Span is Refresh.

How Can I solve the Problem..

Is there any way to dynamically load the jquery.js

Comment: what jquery functionality is not available??? do you want the $().ready() function to be fired when the the span is reloaded???. (The document.ready method will fire only when the document is reloaded and finished reloading), when a particular element is reloaded document.ready will not get fired

Comment: Put the script tag into the head tag!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is [jQuery live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

But I can't be sure unless you tell what you are doing in:

```
// Do Some
```

And what elements are coming from some.jsp.

jQuery live is used to bind event handlers for elements which are later added/replaced in the DOM.